# Is there any way to know the number of imaginary and real solutions to a polynomial by just looking at the equation?

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

For an equation $Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E=0$ or any $n$ degree polynomial with $n \geq 4$, can you tell the number of real and imaginary roots without solving or factoring the equation?

Comment: You know it has $n$ roots total.  By the way "imaginary" does not mean "complex".

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/fundamental-theorem-algebra.html

Comment: Partial results at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Real_roots.

Comment: Not exactly but [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) can narrow down the possible numbers of positive and negative real roots, and in some cases allow you to determine them exactly.

Comment: You can fully tell their number without finding them. See [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

Comment: Look up "Sturm's theorem".

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393967/finding-real-roots-of-a-polynomial-equation-without-graphs).

Comment: What do you mean by "just looking"?

Comment: @mathguy Not actually computing all roots.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but, I know that if we were talking about integers, that we could use the number of odd coefficients as a test for when it could be even. To do so just use odd+odd+odd=odd and odd+odd=even. If there aren't an odd number of  odd coefficients ( including constant term) then the sum of terms is even  at some integer values of x. Since 0 is even, I find this semi relevant, even though it doesn't cover the reals.

Comment: If $E$ and $A$ have opposite signs then there are at last two real roots.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=4$ and real coefficients, lookig [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), you will see that, for , computing a few numbers, you can conclude about the number and nature of the roots.

Just reproducing results given in the Wikipedia page, given $$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$$ compute

$$\Delta=256 a^3 e^3-192 a^2 b d e^2-128 a^2 c^2 e^2+144 a^2 c d^2 e-27 a^2 d^4+144 a b^2 c
   e^2-6 a b^2 d^2 e-80 a b c^2 d e+18 a b c d^3+16 a c^4 e-4 a c^3 d^2-27 b^4
   e^2+18 b^3 c d e-4 b^3 d^3-4 b^2 c^3 e+b^2 c^2 d^2$$ $$P=8 a c-3 b^2 \qquad Q=8 a^2 d-4 a b c+b^3\qquad  \Delta_0=12 a e-3 b d+c^2\qquad D=64 a^3 e-16 a^2 b d-16 a^2 c^2+16 a b^2 c-3 b^4$$ Based on these, you will find the different cases described.

Excluding the case of multiple roots (corresponding to $\Delta=0$), the problem is quite simple :

- if $\Delta <0$,  then the equation has two distinct real roots and two complex conjugate non-real roots.
- if $\Delta >0$, then either the roots are all real or none is

Then, subcases need to be considered.

Comment: What if Δ = 0? I don't know if it is possible, but what will the nature of roots be?

Comment: @AryanJain. Did you go to the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots